# single tap is not working on qlpreviewcontroller

Tags: ios6.1, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I am using qlpreviewcontroller to show images but single tap is not working on it.
How can I add single tap gesture on it. It will work for double tap to zoom in and zoom out images.
Can any body help me to add single tap gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can not add gestures to QLPreviewController. I has fairly limited functionality and is not meant to be modified much.

Answer (score 0):

Please using WKWebView instead of QLPreview

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).